# Complicated counting in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following columns in Excel

```
    a    b    c
 1 SUM  1st  2nd
 2 0    2/2  2/4
 3 0    1/1  3/4
```

b2 is defined as "=CONCATENATE(TRUNC(2);"/";TEXT(('Other sheet'!B2);0))"
and similar to b3,c2,c3.

Column |SUM| should count sum from |1st| to |2nd| but only the first numbers before "/".

for example: b2+c3+... = 2+2+... = 4+... so a2=4+...

any ideas how to do that? :)

Comment: `ZŁĄCZ.TEKSTY` is `CONCATENATE`, `LICZBA.CAŁK` is `TRUNC` and `TEKST` is `TEXT` if you want to edit with an english version to help people understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below formula with feature shift+ctrl+enter:

```
=SUM(TRUNC(MID(B2:C2,1,SEARCH("/",B2:C2,1)-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'left' function

Use it like this

```
A2=left(B2;1)+left(C2;1)
```

Comment: It works for (B2;1)+left(C2;1) but I need it to be for example from B2 to X2.  The other problem is it's not always only 1 character before "/" , for example 10/12.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:C2,"/",".")))
```

Extend your range as far as you need by changing `B2:C2` to `B2:X2`, for example.

---

I *think* this might work for your system.

```
=SUMA.ILOCZYNÓW(ZAOKR.DO.CAŁK(PODSTAW(B2:C2;"/";".")))
```